# Why is the initial prediction of gradient boosting classifier based on log of odds? Why can't we work with probabilities instead?

Tags: boosting

I am unable to understand the role of log odds in GBM classification. Why can't we just work with probabilities?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Where do you see log-odds being used instead of probabilities? Also, since log-odds are transformed probabilities, why do you not see GBMs as using probabilities? If $p$ is the probability, then $\log\left(\dfrac{p}{1-p}\right)$ is the log-odds, and if $L$ is the log-odds, then $\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-L}}$ is the probability. Are you just looking for those relationships?

Answer (score 1):

For the usual reasons that generalized linear models tend to work with logit-probabilities (=log-odds): You add up terms (in the generalized linear model case coefficients $\times$ predictor values, while in the gradient boosted decision tree case you add up the predictions from each tree $\times$ learning rate) and want to ensure that you still get a valid probability (i.e. needs to be between 0 and 1). If you try to somehow achieve that on the probability scale, you end up getting very complicated constraints that are really tricky to ensure (or with some slightly dirty tricks like treating everything <0 as 0 and everything >1 as 1, which might also cause trouble with the differentiability of the loss-function). On the logit scale it's trivial, because every value in $(-\infty, \infty)$ on the logit scale maps to $(0, 1)$ once you apply the inverse transformation (i.e. $\text{expit}(x) = 1/(1+exp(-x))$).